# Desserializar Json em que a chave seja um número

Tags: c#, json, desserialização

Estou tentando desserializar Json com C#, mas encontrei um problema.
No Json pode-se usar números nos nomes das "chaves" (`keys`), mas não podemos usar números em nomes de propriedades no C#

Exemplo:

**Json**:

```
"c":[  
  {  
     "1":23200083,
     "2":"string aleatória",
     "3":0,
     "4":19,
     "5":0,
     "7":9,
     "8":0,
     "9":0,
     "10":0,
     "11":33,
     "12":0,
     "13":999,
     "14":36,
     "15":0,
     "16":1,
     "6":0,
     "17":0
  }
]
```

**C#**:

```
public class C
{

    public string 1 { get; set; }
    public string 2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Eu tentei usar `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2"])`, mas mesmo assim o código não funciona.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiramente, para o json estar válido eu tive que fazer alguns ajustes para ficar conforme abaixo:

```
{
"c":[  
  {  
     "1":23200083,
     "2":"string aleatória",
     "3":0,
     "4":19,
     "5":0,
     "7":9,
     "8":0,
     "9":0,
     "10":0,
     "11":33,
     "12":0,
     "13":999,
     "14":36,
     "15":0,
     "16":1,
     "6":0,
     "17":0
  }]
}
```

Para a class json funcionar, fiz conforme este exemplo (Só fiz para os dois primeiros atributos json, mas depois é só você seguir a ideia):

```
public class CJson
{
    public List<NumericJson> c { get; set; }
}

public class NumericJson
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public int Item1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

E a leitura e confirmação que está funcionando fiz por aplicação console, com este código :

```
    CJson jsonCObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CJson>(jsonToDeserialize);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonCObject.c[0].Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonCObject.c[0].Item2);
```

Se precisar de uma referência [em inglês veja esta pergunta 'Access JSON fields with numeric keys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213186/access-json-fields-with-numeric-keys)

Answer (score 2):

Utilizado um [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) é possível desserializar esse *json* em uma propriedade do tipo `Dictionary<string,string>` ou numa `List<Item>`, com a classe *Item* declarada desta forma:

```
public class Item
{
    //Note que o nome das propriedades pode ser outro qualquer.
    public string Key { get;}
    public string Value { get;}

    public Item(string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

A vantagem é que, qualquer que seja o número de pares `"key":"value"`, a classe para receber o resultado é sempre a mesma.

O único senão é que os valores inteiros desserializados terão de ser convertidos para *string*, o que julgo não ser impeditivo para a utilização do resultado.

### Desserializar para `Dictionary<string,string>`:

Classe para receber o resultado da desserialização.

```
public class CJson
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MapJsonConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> C { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Json Converter.

```
public class MapJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!CanConvert(objectType))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(
                string.Format($"Can't cast from {objectType} to {typeof (Dictionary<string, string>)}");
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            reader.Read();//Start object
            reader.Read();//Object
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                {
                    var key = reader.Value.ToString();
                    reader.Read();//Next Token
                    var value = reader.Value.ToString();
                    map.Add(key,value);
                }
                reader.Read();//Next Token
            }
            return map;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected Json content");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
                                   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

**Nota:** Se o conjunto de pares `"key":"value"` tivessem os valores(value) todos do mesmo tipo, a desserialização poderia ser feita directamente numa propriedade do tipo `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, sem necessidade de um JsonConverter.

### Desserializar para `List<Item>`:

Classe para receber o resultado da desserialização.

```
public class CJson
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MapJsonConverter))]
    public IList<Item> C { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Json Converter.

```
public class MapJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!CanConvert(objectType))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(
                string.Format($"Can't cast from {objectType} to {typeof (List<Item>)}");
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            var list = new List<Item>();
            reader.Read();//Start object
            reader.Read();//Object
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                {
                    var key = reader.Value.ToString();
                    reader.Read();//Next Token
                    var value = reader.Value.ToString();
                    var item = new Item(key, value);
                    list.Add(item);
                }
                reader.Read();//Next Token
            }
            return list;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected Json content");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IList<Item>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) ||
               typeof(List<Item>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
                                   JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Em ambos os casos, use

```
CJson result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CJson>(jsonString);
```

para desserializar.